# Function of quantum operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

How I can calculate $\cos(a a^\dagger)$, where $a$ and $a^\dagger$ are boson operators? I tried to expand the cosine function but I do not get an analytical formula.

Comment: You want to calculate the spectrum of this operator?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite understand your statements on analyticity, but you know that
$ a a^\dagger =   a^\dagger a +1 \equiv N+1, $ so that
$$\cos(a a^\dagger)= \cos (N+1),$$
which is quite well-behaved.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try
$$\cos (a a^\dagger)=\frac{e^{i a a^\dagger}+e^{-i a a^\dagger}}{2}=\frac{e^{i a^\dagger a}e^i+e^{-i a^\dagger a}e^{-i}}{2}.$$ This is a perfectly valid operator, no problems! The regular number states will be its eigenstates, as could be obtained from just doing $\cos(a a^\dagger)|n\rangle=\cos(1+a^\dagger a)|n\rangle=\cos(1+n)|n\rangle$, and the rest follows.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was thinking about convergences of the result